# Имеется большое число. Как разместить точки или пробелы через каждую третью цифру?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Число размещается под `<input>` или `<div>` и меняется в зависимости от действий пользователя. Не важно как. Важно, чтобы большие числа отображались не в виде 200000000, а 200 000 000 или 200.000.000

Скажем, можно создать много input-ов рядом друг с другом и в каждый из них вывести отдельную циферку из всего числа, но тогда получаются слишком запутанные формулы:

```
value = Math.floor(число/10000000);
value = Math.floor((Число - Math.floor(число/10000000)*10000000))/1000000);
```

и т.п., еще и придется учитывать количество знаков в числе (200 000 000 был примером, там может быть и 10 000, и что угодно), и отдельно прописать формулы для каждого количества знаков. Может есть способ полегче?

---

UPD: собстно, применяя ответ Ивана к моему вопросу, решение:

```
<input id="input" value="100000000">

<script>document.getElementById("input").value = new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format( document.getElementById("input").value );</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Объект `Intl.NumberFormat` является конструктором объектов, включающих языко-зависимое форматирование чисел.

```js
var number = 123456.789;
// В России в качестве разделителя целой и дробной части используется запятая,
// а в качестве разделителя разрядов - пробел
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(number));
// → 123 456,789
```

Подробнее в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Comment: На крайняк .match(/\d{1,3}/g).join(whatever) Кстати, то что вытащено из инпута - всегда строка!